# How can I find alfresco empty foldres using Lucene Query

Tags: search, lucene, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I want to retrieve the list of folders in a specific node whose list of childrens is empty using `Lucene query`.

I create this query:

```
+PATH:"/app:company_home/cm:contexts/cm:ctx_exploitation/cm:runs/cm:Run_322645//."+Children is empty.
```

but it does not give good results.

What is the right `Lucene` syntax to do this

Comment: There's no way to do this with a single Lucene query.

Comment: CMIS is an option (supports JOINs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to find empty folders using a Lucene query.
However, there are some java services and javascript APIs in alfresco 
like 'FileFolderService' in Java and 'childByNamePath' in javascript,
using them you can write your logic and find empty folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can find o bytes file using below lucene query.

TYPE:"cm:content" AND @cm:content.size:0

Comment: the complete sentence could be something like the following, as @sanjay said :) PATH:"/app:company_home/cm:contexts/cm:ctx_exploitation/cm:runs/cm:Run_322645//*" AND TYPE:"cm:content" AND @cm\:content.size:0