# Alfresco: Search all nodes without parents

Tags: alfresco

I'd like to know how to get all nodes of a given type `ts:folderSet` which has no parent association of type `ts:FolderSubSet` informed.

Currently:

[image]

So, I mean, I need all nodes of type `ts:folderSet` where `tsfss:folderSubSet-folder` is null or not informed.

Currently, I'm using admin tool in order to build this query, but I'll need to use it into a java code.

[image]

So I mean, I can use FTS or lucene...
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find alfresco empty foldres using Lucene Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902243/how-can-i-find-alfresco-empty-foldres-using-lucene-query)

Answer (score 0):

If your parent type is different you can do:
+TYPE:"ts:folderSet"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the PARENT keyword in search uses the primary parent. Your ts:folderSubSet object is a secondary parent to your ts:folderSet object. I don't think you will be able to write a single query that can find instances of ts:folderSet that do not have an instance of ts:folderSubSet as a secondary parent.

You can write a query that returns ts:folderSet objects and then you can iterate over each one of the results checking its list of parents for the secondary object. Not ideal, but it is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score -1):

You can search for a type of nodes using the following Lucene query

```
TYPE:"cm:folder"
```

Comment: Yes, but what about this node has no parent?

Comment: Any node in alfresco will be of a specific type. It may be a folder, a document or it can be a user. You can search any node by its type.